# Get varBinary data from database and display C#

Tags: sql

I retrieve a data, whose datatype is `varbinary` from `database` and display it, but the data display is totally different

The data in `database` is

```
0x0400000000200040000000000018
```

But when it `display` is

```
BAAAAAAgAEAAAAAAABg=
```

Is there anywhere to display it as

```
0x0400000000200040000000000018?
```

Comment: What is your  datatype of the coulmn @Siang

Comment: Which dbms are you using??

Comment: The datatype of the column in database is varbinary @HardikParmar

Comment: Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio @AnkitBajpai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then simply you can do is 
Change your datatype from

```
varbinary
```

to

```
varchar(500)
```

**OR**

Try this Also

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),coulmn_name,2)
```

that will solve your issue

**EDIT**

You can do simply like this

```
SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),coulmn_name,2) FROM TB_USER
```

Comment: Please check the above edited answer. I am not sure but I think this will work @Siang

Comment: Please check I have made final update to the answer this will surely work I have tested it @Siang

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue.
If my sql statement is SELECT * FROM TB_USER
and one of the column is in VarBinary, is there any idea to apply that solution in this scenario?

Comment: If the statement is "SELECT * FROM TB_USER" only, and one of the column that return from database is VarBinary?
Sorry for that, I edit here.

Comment: Hardik, last time I try CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),coulmn_name,2) still can return '0400000000200040000000000018', but now when I try again it return '@', is there anything will cause this issue? @HardikParmar

Comment: what you have tried please give me the value & full query

Comment: The value inside database is 0x0400000000200040000000000018
My Query is SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),AccessRights,2) FROM TB_USER
Without the convert, it return BAAAAAAgAEAAAAAAABg=
With convert, it return @ @HardikParmar

Comment: I am getting proper output I have created test data tabe please check this

Comment: create table bbb
( 
 col1 varbinary(max) 
)

insert bbb
values
(0x0400000000200040000000000018)

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),col1,2),col1 from bbb